# The statement $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{n}=a\neq0 \implies |a_n-a|< \frac{1}{n}$ with $n$ big enough is true or false?

Tags: limits

> The statement $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{n}=a \neq0\implies |a_n-a|< \frac{1}{n}$ with $n$ big  enough is true or false?

The answer in exercise said the statement is not true.

Maybe it's wrong because  the $\varepsilon$ everytime only choose a definite constant, not a variable.

But I don't really know how to explain it , on contrast I think the statement is correct.

Because we can let $\varepsilon= \frac{1}{n}$.

Therefore:$$ |a_n-a|< \frac{1}{n}= \varepsilon (n~~big ~~enough)$$

It conforms to the limit definition.

how to analyze the statement not by taking example? just to prove it is wrong directly?

Comment: Take $a=0$, $a_n =1000/n$. Does your claim hold in this case?

Answer (score 2):

It's false even if you replace $1/n$ with $C/n$ where $C$ is some real constant. Take for example $a_n=1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$. Then $a_n\to a=1$ and 
$$|a_n-a|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}<\frac{C}{n} $$
does not hold eventually (or for $n$ big enough) for ANY real constant $C$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the sequence $$a_n=\frac {2}{n}$$ which tends to $0$ . 
Clearly $$|a_n-0|=\frac {2}{n}>\frac {1}{n}$$

Comment: how to analyze the statement not by taking example? just to prove it is wrong directly?